# How to create pseudo border content with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css, pseudo-element, tailwind-elements

So, I'm trying to make a top and bottom border on a nav menu in Tailwind CSS, I've tried using `border-b-4` and `border-t-4` with `bg-indigo-500` but the border and the background didn't split at each other. I wonder if I can use it using pseudo-element or is there any better method for this? thank you!

here's my code :

```
'inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-4 border-t-4 border-indigo-400 text-sm font-medium bg-indigo-500 leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
```

I want it to look like this :

[image: Border nav with pseudo-element tailwind CSS]

But instead, this is what I got :

[image: Border nav tailwind CSS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done. I have write some steps for you to just need to follow. I have added working example below plz check it.

1. Add `<span>` tag in button
2. add `padding` and `background` color to the `<span>` tag
3. remove `background` from `<button>` and add `padding` or `border` in `<button>` tag.

```
<button type="button"
    class="inline-flex items-center py-2 border-b-4 border-t-4 border-indigo-400 text-sm font-medium  leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
    <span class="p-3 bg-indigo-500">Click Me</span>
</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's working, now I just need to figure out how to put an active condition on each navigation